# How to edit quicklist for a Mounted Device in the launcher?

Tags: quicklists

I know how to add quicklists for a standard launcher with a .desktop file in either ~/.local/share/applications or /usr/share/applications.

But I am  trying to create a quicklist for the icon that appears when a blank disc (CDR/DVD) is inserted.

Comment: I want _Format_ for USB devices.

Answer (score 1):

A similar discussion took place in the Ayatana Mailing List. It is not possible to create a quicklist for mounted devices or CDs by just editing the .desktop files. You need to hard code this in Unity itself.

Comment: Yes, that was me. Just seeing if the community knows how I could go about this myself.

Comment: oh ok..You should then ask Didrocks or Omer Akram who work on Unity code themselves. They will be able to point you in the right direction. Contact them through IRC.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit any of those .desktop files, whichever one you plan on having on your Unity bar to feature your command as a right-click shortcut. You can edit an existing shortcut and change the icon.

To create a launcher that has the blank disc icon, you can do that graphically either in the menu editor (`alacarte`) or even using a Nautilus script, then find your blank disc icon (icon sets normally have them in the `.../devices/` folder), or get a template for a `.desktop` file and put the path to that icon in the `Icon=` field. Since the launcher will have the blank disc icon, now you can use the existing quicklist examples as a template and add all the right-click shortcuts you like.

Comment: I don't think this is right in this case. If I'm understanding the question, they want to be add entries to the quicklist for a mounted volume, specifically a blank CD, rather than adding an arbitrary launcher with a disk icon. Mounted volumes seem to occupy their own category in the Unity launcher, and I don't know of any way to edit their launcher entries.